# Simple Electron ThreeJS/Bootstrap/JQuery App not woking

Tags: javascript, jquery, electron

I am new to Electron and I am trying to build a simple app that includes THREEJS, Bootstrap, and Jquery.

I am having all kinds of issues.

Here is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "sample",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^1.8.4",
    "electron-packager": "^11.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "popper": "^1.0.1",
    "three": "^0.91.0"
  }
}
```

I installed all packages by using `npm install <package> --save`

What else do I need to do ?

The only thing that works is JQuery. When I type in the console `$` I get back jquery.

Nothing else works. Bootstrap is not rendering CSS at all, THREEJS is not defined in the console.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to the problem in not loading Bootstrap, include the following script tag:

```
<script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');</script>
```

Hope this helps!!